# How to Sync Database Data to a Desktop Application without using internet

Tags: android, android-layout, android-emulator

I have a desktop application in .NET and I want to make an Android application which will sync its database to the desktop without using the Internet. Is there any way to sync this database over a USB connection?

In Android I'm storing the data in a SQLite database.

Comment: Anyone Suggest me an idea to Sync Application Database to Desktop Application without Using Internet...

Comment: can it be interactive with `adb`? You could use adb to transfer the file from your emulator to your desktop and vice versa

Comment: Yah..Using adb we can push and pull DB. That i know..but that's not i needed..i want my app in android device push and pull data's to Database in Desktop with-out the help of internet..

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can. You need to create your database using [SqliteDatabase.create()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#create%28android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory%29). And give to it SD-Card path. then you can download this file to your pc, manipulate it and upload it back to to your android device.